# Boost thread interupt does not work when crossing a DLL boundary

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm porting an application onto Windows and have found that when interrupting a boost::thread across a DLL boundary, the thread does not get interrupted.

The boost libraries are linked statically and are built with multithreading support using debug runtime and linking to shared runtime libraries. /MDd

The project is compiled using msvc12 (2013) (the same compiler that boost was compiled in).

I've made a short example project that demonstrates the issue:

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/thread.hpp"
#include "test_library.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  qDebug() << "Hello";

  Test_library test;

  qDebug() << "Starting thread";
  boost::thread thread = boost::thread(&Test_library::Loop, &test);
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(3));

  qDebug() << "interrupt thread";
  thread.interrupt();

  qDebug() << "Joining thread";
  thread.join();

  qDebug() << "Closing Program";
  return 0;
}
```

test_library.cpp

```
#include "test_library.h"
#include "boost/thread.hpp"


void Test_library::Loop()
{

  qDebug() << "Starting loop";
  while(true)
  {
    qDebug() << "Looping";
    boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(500));
  }

  qDebug() << "Looping finished";
}
```

test_library.h

```
#pragma once
#include "test_library_global.h"
#include <QtCore>

class TEST_LIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT Test_library
{
public:
  void Loop();
};
```

TestProject.pro (QMake file)

```
DESTDIR = ../TestProjectDeploy/

SOURCES += \
    test.cpp


LIBS += -L$$DESTDIR -ltest_library


include(../BoostIncludes.pri)

DESTDIR = ../TestProjectDeploy/

QT       -= gui

TARGET = test_library
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += TEST_LIBRARY_LIBRARY

SOURCES += test_library.cpp

HEADERS += test_library.h
```

TestLibrary.pro

```
include(../BoostIncludes.pri)

DESTDIR = ../TestProjectDeploy/

QT       -= gui

TARGET = test_library
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += TEST_LIBRARY_LIBRARY

SOURCES += test_library.cpp

HEADERS += test_library.h\
        test_library_global.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

BoostIncludes.pri

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Libraries/boost_1_60_0/" 

LIBS = "-LC:/Libraries/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/"  \
"C:/Libraries/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_60.lib" \
"C:/Libraries/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_60.lib" \
"C:/Libraries/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/libboost_chrono-vc120-mt-gd-1_60.lib" \
"C:/Libraries/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/libboost_timer-vc120-mt-gd-1_60.lib" \
```

Program output:

```
Hello
Starting thread
Starting loop
Looping
Looping
Looping
Looping
Looping
Looping
interrupt thread
Looping
Joining thread
Looping
Looping
Looping
Looping
Looping
Looping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to not linking dynamically to boost threads dlls.
Also a pre-processor macro is needed in all projects

```
DEFINES += BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL


################### WINDOWS ###################
WINDOWS_BOOST_DEBUG_DLL = "-LC:/Libraries/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/"  \
-l"boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_60"\
-l"boost_chrono-vc120-mt-gd-1_60"\
-l"boost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_60"\
-l"boost_timer-vc120-mt-gd-1_60"\
```